# Dockerized Webscrapers

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to execute my web scraper within a Docker environment. The error message being returned states: "JavaScript error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'shadowRoot')". This error arises specifically when the execution reaches the line responsible for closing the pop-up page:

```
deny_all_button = browser.execute_script('return
document.getElementById("usercentrics-root").shadowRoot.getElementById("uc-cnil-deny-all")')
```

I'm kinda new to Docker usage, and I'm uncertain about the appropriate course of action to resolve this problem. It is worth noting that the web scraper functions correctly when executed locally on PyCharm.
I have also verified the correctness of the JavaScript line and confirmed that it successfully locates the relevant element on the website.

Comment: What is the Dockerized script seeing, because currently the error states that the element property is null (not there) has the element been appropriately updated in the script?

Comment: I fixed the issue, by running this command system prune --all and rebuild my docker image again. I assume it was related to running a broken image